# Clearing all sharedprefs from menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have been struggling with implementing a "clear preferences" option in the 3dot (overflow) menu... sample screen shot here:

[image]

Coding wise... I tried this but it does not do the job:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.clearsp) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dyna_cb_prf", 0);
            preferences.edit().clear().commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Tips on how to modify this? Basically, I want it to clear ALL sharedprefs upon clicking that option (I may have multiple xml files to clear sometimes)

Comment: I tried that before posting, but it just triggers a choose app dialog box... my code was:if (id == R.id.clearsp) {
            getSharedPreferences("dyna_cb_prf", 0).edit().clear().commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            startActivity(i);
        }

Comment: No, the issue is that I cannot get the menu item to trigger the removal. I have a screen shot in my main post on the menu item... I basically want to click that and purge all sharedprefs

Comment: Yup, it is working perfectly fine for other menu items (they are URLs)

Comment: I think my issue is that I have to call on the intent.. but I am not sure how. Have a look at this: https://i.imgur.com/uTugJ41.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a SharedPreferencesManager class, that keeps track of all the different SharedPreference xml files, and has a method to clear them all.

Simple example with two types of SharedPreferences:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    public static SharedPreferences forDynaCpPrf(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("dyna_cb_prf", 0);
    }

    public static SharedPreferences forSomethingElse(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("something_else", 0);
    }

    public static void clearAllSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {

        forDynaCpPrf(ctx).edit().clear().commit();
        forSomethingElse(ctx).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

Then, if the user selects the menu item to Clear Preferences, just call the `clearAllSharedPreferences()` method:

```
if (id == R.id.clearsp) {
  SharedPreferencesManager.clearAllSharedPreferences(this);
}
```

Note that instead of calling `getSharedPreferences("dyna_cb_prf", 0)` outside of the SharedPreferencesManager class, you would just call the `forDynaCpPrf()` method:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = SharedPreferencesManager.forDynaCpPrf(this);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Could I also just do this as an alternate? https://i.imgur.com/PPXm3MO.png

Comment: @Adam, yes, that would work, but if you don't have it in a centralized class, it will get messy eventually.  For instance, if you have ten SharedPreference  xml files, whenever you want to delete all, it would be ten lines of code instead of just one.

Comment: Yes, completely agreed. Your solution is much more organized. I will opt for that but just wanted to check if both would work :) Thanks a lot!